# installed ClosedXml nuget from nuget manager but can't load an existing Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, openxml, closedxml

I installed ClosedXml nuget from nuget manager but can't load an existing excel file.

```
string file = "test.xlsx";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + file)))
            {
                var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + file);

                //var workbook = new XLWorkbook(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + file));
                var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
```

or I did like

```
var stream = ExcelHelper.getExcelFileAsStream();
var workbook = new XLWorkbook(stream);
```

Nothing works. Getting:

> object instance not set an instance of an object on line.

Code:

```
 var workbook = new XLWorkbook(stream);
```

Comment: I would have to see the actual file to determine what is causing the exception. Please log an issue with full details at http://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML and attach the file. Remove any sensitive info from the file.

Comment: Will log and attach file as well

Comment: Issue posted here https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/55

Comment: I have submitted a pull request which should fix that issue.